# Angular 5 TypeError: this.tipp.isPersistent is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

Don't what the problem is. While logging to console the following error is displayed:

```
"Tipp: {
"id":1,
 {...}
}

ERROR TypeError: this.tipp.isPersistent is not a function" is shown.
```

The first log statement is displayed correctly. But it seems to be a problem to evaluate '**this.tipp.isPersistent()**':

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tipp-eingabe',
  templateUrl: './tipp-eingabe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tipp-eingabe.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TippEingabeComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() tipp: Tipp;    
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log("Tipp: " + JSON.stringify(this.tipp));
    console.log("Tipp-isPersistent: " + this.tipp.isPersistent());
  }
}

export class Tipp {
  id: number;
  spieler: Spieler;
  spiel: Spiel;
  tippErgebnis: Spielstand;
  aenderungsDatum: Date;

  public isPersistent(): boolean  {
    return true;
  };
}
```

Called by following template snippet:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel panel-body">
    <div *ngFor="let spiel of spiele">
      <div *ngIf="!isMatchCollapsed(spiel.id)">
        <div *ngFor="let tipp of spiel.tipps" class="tippLine">
          <tipp-eingabe [tipp]="tipp"></tipp-eingabe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are creating an object with the properties of `Tipp` instead of creating a new instance of `Tipp`. This means your object has the properties of `Tipp`, but not the methods.

So in your parent component that passes tipp into TippEingabeComponent you should be creating a new instance of `Tipp`.

```
let tipp = new Tipp(// pass in params);
```

This means you'll have to update your Tipp class to accept parameters

```
export class Tipp {
    id: number;
    spieler: Spieler;
    spiel: Spiel;
    tippErgebnis: Spielstand;
    aenderungsDatum: Date;

    constructor(obj: {
        id: number;
        spieler: Spieler;
        spiel: Spiel;
        tippErgebnis: Spielstand;
        aenderungsDatum: Date;
    }){
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.spieler = obj.spieler;
        this.spiel = obj.spiel;
        this.tippErgebnis = obj.tippErgebnis;
        this.aenderungsDatu = obj.aenderungsDatum;
    }

    public isPersistent(): boolean  {
        return true;
    };
}
```

Now when your TippEngabeComponent calls the method isPersistent it will exist on tipp because tipp is an instance of the class Tipp.

Comment: How can I do that?     
The tipps are delivered by an service from a database as an embedded property of Spiel class:

    export class Spiel {
      id: number;
         :
      tipps: Tipp[];
    }

Comment: @user1350889 when you are building out the `spiel.tipps` array in your parent component, you should be creating a new instance of the class for each tipp. so something like `spiel.tipps = [new Tipp(...), new Tipp(...), new Tipp(...)];`

Answer (score 0):

You should just call **`this.isPersistent()`**

```
 console.log("Tipp-isPersistent: " + this.isPersistent());
```

Comment: Does not work: Compiler failure: 'Property 'isPersistent' does not exist on type 'TippEingabeComponent'

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  console.log("Tipp changed: " + JSON.stringify(this.tipp));
  console.log("this.tipp instanceof Tipp: " + (this.tipp instanceof Tipp));
  console.log("Tipp wurde geändert: " + this.tipp.isPersistent());
}
```

Put in some more debug info reults into:

```
Tipp changed: {"id":1, ..... }
this.tipp instanceof Tipp: false
ERROR TypeError: this.tipp.isPersistent is not a function
```

As the log output says the tipp is not an instance of class Tipp. But why not? 
The data is delivered as part of an quit complex json tree from a backend service. I thought that the instantiation of the embedded leafes/nodes of the tree is handled by angular?

```
export class Spiel {
  id: number;
   :
  tipps: Tipp[];
}
```

Is it wrong to assume, that the embedded 'tipps' delivered by a data service in json are instantiated as 'Tipp' types as declared in 'Spiel' class definition?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "tipps": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "spieler": {
        "id": 2,
        "spielerName": "Stumbe",
        "email": "petrajautz@gmx.de",
        "rolle": "Spieler"
      },
      "tippErgebnis": {
        "toreTeam1": 1,
        "toreTeam2": 2
      },
      "aenderungsDatum": "2017-12-27T10:08:15"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "spieler": {
        "id": 3,
        "spielerName": "Aug",
        "email": "auge.sumser@gmx.de",
        "rolle": "Admin"
      },
      "tippErgebnis": {
        "toreTeam1": 1,
        "toreTeam2": 1
      },
      "aenderungsDatum": "2017-12-27T10:08:15"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: json returned from a data service is simply json. the angular http client is responsible for retrieving your data. you are responsible for transforming that data as needed. In your case, instantiating your custom classes. Doing `tipps: Tipp[]` only means that `tipps` is of the type array of `Tipp`. It does not do any instantiation.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer?